# JQuery Plugin: Expanding Boxes / Sliding Panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Wondering if anyone out there has seen any jQuery plugins that will allow me to take a grid of divs 5x5 and have the :hovered div expand to a designated size, simultaneously shrinking all other divs to a certain (smaller but) equal size?

Example: All of the div's would start out 50px high, 50px wide and then the hovered div would expand to be 90px x 90px while the other 24 would shrink to be 10px x 10px :)  Does that make sense?

I thought I saw a plugin like this before but I'm completely striking out in Google searches for a plugin of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these demos here of JQuery LavaLamp.  It seems like this could be something you tweak to work how you describe.

http://nixboxdesigns.com/projects/jquery-lavalamp/demos.php

**UPDATE**:

I found exactly what you're looking for.  These are MacOS style dock menus!

http://www.wizzud.com/jqDock/

Comment: Thanks jmort.  Good stuff but I'm holding out for something closer that I don't have to modify so heavily.  All of the div's would start out 50px high, 50px wide and then the hovered div would expand to be 90px wide / high while the other 24 would shrink to be 10px x 10px :)  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Oh, that second one is much better :)  I think I can make this work... thanks!

Comment: @Brian - Awesome!  I thought that would help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Soh Tanaka's excellent tutorial](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/) on thumbnail hovers. It's not a plugin but does pretty much what you want except for reducing the size of the other thumbnails which is pretty easy to achieve eg.

```
.animate({width: '10px', height: '10px'}).
```